# Create an interface for ProgressDialog

Tags: android, interface, progressdialog, java

I am writing a `java-library` to use with an Android-Client

- I perform a job for which I **CAN** display a `ProgressDialog` (suppose using `AsyncTask`).
- Rather than displaying the dialog through the library, I want to do it by creating an interface (to be included in the library) which can be implemented in the application layer, i.e. By the developer who uses the library and can customize the dialog himself. (by customize I mean, the interface may provide some themes, which could be selected by passing an `ENUM` to a function, or something like that)

  I have no clue how to do that. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Comment: lot of examples are there. just google with `android custom progress dialog`

Comment: i know how to customize the dialog, but that's not what this question seeks for, please read again :-)